# Independence and Nuances (Finding independent events)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, independence

I have this problem stating:

> Assume A,B,C,D are pairwise independent events. Decide if $A \cap B$
>   and $B \cap D$ are independent events. Then repeat this assuming the
>   four events are mutually independent.

I know mutually independent means $P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D) = P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)$. And, in this case, that pairwise independence is when

$$P_A(B) = P(B)$$
$$P_A(C) = P(C)$$
$$P_A(D) = P(D)$$
$$P_B(C) = P(C)$$
$$P_B(D) = P(D)$$
$$P_C(D) = P(D)$$

However, my problem is I don't know how to start this problem nor how to solve this without given values for the events. If anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A very similar question was asked on MSE less than an hour ago. It has been answered, and should not be hard to find.

Comment: I saw it, but I didn't really understand. I was hoping someone could explain it in simpler terms.

Comment: There is some detail left to the reader, namely (in the first part) the pairwise independence of $A$, $B$, and $D$ as defined there (two coin tosses, unlike the three in the Remark). To show that for example $A$ (head on first toss) and $B$ (both the same) are independent, note that $\Pr(A)=1/2$, $\Pr(B)=1/2$ (both heads or both tails) and $\Pr(A\cap B)=1/4$ (two heads). So $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$, which is the definition of independence.

Comment: Thank you, the part I was confused about was what if $B \cap D$ and $C \cap D$ are both intended? Do you think the problem is not worded correctly?

Comment: The first part of my answer deals with the question as stated by both of you. The answer is that $A\cap B$ and $B\cap D$ are not necessarily independent. The proof is by giving a (counter)example. The part in the Remark deals with the most plausible question if there is really a typo.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome.