# Pairwise Independent Events

Tags: probability, independence

The question states: "Assume A,B,C,D are pairwise independent events. Decide if A ∩ B and B ∩ D are independent events. Then repeat this assuming the four events are mutually independent." I am not sure how to go about doing this proof and could use some insight on how to do it.

Comment: Well, to solve this problem, you first have to know what independent means.  What does it mean for two events $A$ and $B$ to be independent?  Without the answer to this, you won't be able to solve the problem.

Comment: A would be independent from B if P(A|B) = P(A)

Comment: Looks like someone else in your class already posted this problem earlier today: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468324